# How to automatically update an area chart in Highcharts with data located in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I currently have data in Google Sheets that updates every second. My current chart retrieves this data initially, but I would like it to refresh every second with this new data. My categories along the x-axis are to remain static.

My javascript code is as follows:

```
$(function () {
    // Create the chart
    $('#areaStack').highcharts({

     chart: {

            type: 'area',

            events : {

                load: function() {

                    setInterval(function(){

                       this.series[0].setData([this.data],true,true,true); 
                    }, 1000); 
                }
            } 
        },

        plotOptions: {

            area: {

                lineWidth: 1,
                stacking: null
            }
        },

        data: {
            googleSpreadsheetKey: '1wkXWhKK8nL53NSc7IqXILVl6oPYEZnNtio',
        }

    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a `setInterval` function to update your chart every second?

Comment: Thanks @RocoCTZ. This was my intention. Code has been updated.

Comment: Have you tried to use soluton like here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4878 ?

Comment: Thanks @SebastianBochan but I think my JS skills aren't good enough to to take this solution and apply it to my particular problem.